# git large file system

Tags: git

I am new to git large file system but things are extremely confusing to me. Basically, I try to reset everything as on the git repository. By just doing git checkout master, some files have local changes and then re-switching becomes hard..... Why? This issue is very painful, since all pull, push are all affected!!!!

```
221:$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
221:$ git checkout dev1.1
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    FOLDER/equity.csv
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
221:$ git reset --hard 
HEAD is now at b89fcff the latest code in AWS to identify all difference and keep track
221:$ git checkout dev1.1
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    FOLDER/equity.csv
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would write **$ git status** you would see that you changed the file "FOLDER/equity.csv". If you change a file git will recognize that and will mark it as changed but will not add it to the changelist. With "git reset --hard" you only delete all changes that are tagged for the next commit (via git add).
The other thing which is making trouble is that the file FOLDER/equity.csv in the branch dev1.1 is different to the current branch. The file in the current branch is changed but not committed so git would need to delete all your changes you made to check out to the branch dev1.1 which it is not supposed to.

If you want to save the changes you made and check out the new branch after that:

- $ git add FOLDER/equity.csv
- $ git commit -m "Commit message. What did you change?"
- $ git checkout dev1.1

If you want to delete your changes:

- $ git checkout -- FOLDER/equality.csv
- $ git checkout dev1.1

If you want to save your changes for future working on without commiting:

- $ git stash
- $ git checkout dev1.1

For future problems: Try to find a tutorial for git which suits your needs and try that on a dedicated test repository. it will save you trouble :D
Use "git status" to view the current status of git and to see why something could possibly not work.

Here are two links to git guides which looks quite easy to understand.

- https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
- https://blog.udemy.com/git-tutorial-a-comprehensive-guide/

Answer (score 2):

If you have made changes to some files that you have not committed yet, and you check out different versions of those files from another branch, they will overwrite the modified files, causing you to lose the changes. By default, Git will refuse to do this and give you a warning, but you can override it with the --force (-f) flag.

**But it is always recommended to commit your local changes before switching to other branch.**